# Is this an appropriate use of the Service Locator Pattern in my MVC 3 ModelBinder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns, ninject

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application and am using Ninject for injecting dependencies into my classes.

Actions on the Controllers pass ViewModels (that do not contain logic) to the view layer.

When a HTTP form is POSTed MVC 3 creates a ViewModel instance and binds the incoming POST data to the ViewModel's properties. MVC 3 uses a class called DefaultModelBinder to create the instance and perform the binding.

Most of my ViewModels share a dependency which I do not really want to set from each individual Controller method (DRY principle).

Therefore, I have created a customized subclass of DefaultModelBinder as follows:

```
using System;

using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Application.Classes {

    public sealed class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder {

        private readonly IDependencyResolver DependencyResolver;

        public CustomModelBinder( IDependencyResolver dependencyResolver ) {

            DependencyResolver = dependencyResolver;

        }

        protected override object CreateModel( ControllerContext controllerContext , ModelBindingContext modelBindingContext , Type modelType ) {

            return DependencyResolver.GetService( modelType );

        }

    }

}
```

And I have set it to replace the DefaultModelBinder as follows (in Global.asax.cs):

```
protected void Application_Start() {

    // ...

    ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CustomModelBinder( DependencyResolver.Current );

    // ...

}
```

By doing this when a Controller method receives a ViewModel, it will be one that was built by Ninject using the binding I sepecified in my NinjectModule. The ViewModel now receives it's dependencies injected into it's constructor.

Is this an appropriate use of the Service Locator Pattern?

CLARIFICATION/UPDATES:

- The application uses Ninject and is integrated into the MVC system as documented on the Ninject Wiki (https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application)

Comment: I am curious which dependency your viewmodels could require, because a viewmodel should be as stupid as possible. And you could use ninject to inject the dependency into your controller which in turn could pass it to the constructor of the viewmodel.

Comment: @Peter Well, you don't have access to the constructor of the ViewModel from the Controller in MVC 3 (unless I am missing something). The ViewModels (the ones that MVC 3 creates for you as an Action parameter) are created in a "Black Box" called DefaultModelBinder.

Comment: @Peter I am open to explore the dependency in the ViewModel. But I do really want to understand if this CustomModelBinder is an appropriate use of the Service Locator Pattern (I am trying to get my head around many of these concepts!).

Comment: OK, so the dependency is a ViewModelBase.AccountInformation which is received in the constructor of an abstract class ViewModelBase. It is used on all "logged in" pages to display how much Credit an account has left, and their renewal date.

Comment: I've added my answer, hopefully Its made things a bit clearer. If you still have questions, I would really like to discuss them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand so far is that you have a ViewModel which inherits from ViewModelBase to expose AccountInformation on all Views where a user is logged in.

Unless I completely misunderstood, this is my point of view:
The AccountInformation should only be used for displaying purposes. So it should not be a problem when the default ModelBinder does not instantiate it when a post to your action occurs. I encourage you to fetch the AccountInformation again using the information you have eg. `Controller.User` and your database. A registration/profile page is the only place where you'd want this information to come from POST variables. You could cache this information per user if necessary.

As I said in the comments, ViewModels should be as stupid as possible. They should only contain the properties with their types and metadata regarding validation etc.

All the logic you'd want to put in a view, goes into the controller.

So to conclude; There shouldn't be the need to use a Service Locator in your ModelBinder.

Comment: It is true that when a POST action occurs the AccountInformation is often not needed - except of course for the case where there has been a validation error and the Action needs to re-render the View. It sounds like for each Action in each Controller I would need to repeat the line(s) of code to populate this ViewModelBase property. Can you elaborate as to why dependency injection would not be a preferable solution? And given the DRY principal, why repeating oneself is acceptable over a single point of object graph configuration.

Comment: Why not just add a Html.RenderAction("Account/Information") in your master page? That way you follow the DRY principle and even better, you no longer have to couple this data to your other viewmodels.

Comment: That sounds like a great solution. It's benefits are clear as you have described. Thanks for taking the time to think about this.

Answer (score 2):

View Models should not have dependecies. They are just dumb data containers with no functionallity. Use Filters for cross cutting concerns instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not disagreeing that a Filter maybe better suited for this task, but would you help me to understand why the CustomModelBinder is not the best solution.

Comment: Just for clarification, the injected AccountInformation instance is a DTO without any functionality. In this way the ViewModel is still a dumb data container.

Comment: Creating the DTO isn't the problem. But somewhere this DTO needs to get its data from. It shouldn't do it itsself because it wouldn't be a dumb DTO's anymore. It shouldn't be done by the model binder either because its responsibility is to provide the view model instances and not their content. The controller is not the correct location either because of DRY. A Ninject activation action feels to be too magic. You can't see in the implementation where the data is comming from. What's left is a filter. This way you can also have different implementations for different controllers easily.

Comment: Thanks for a great breakdown! I would challenge you on what you think the ModelBinder is responsible for. It doesn't just provide view model instances without their content. Indeed it's main function is to bind content into the view model instances (via the Bind* methods). That said, I do agree with you that different approach is needed. I tried to create the filter, but I couldn't find a way to use constructor injection to inject the dependency. I personally refuse to use property injection as it is too much like magic! I think the Html.RenderAction() approach is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using Ninject for MVC3? You can download it from [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc)

Then in your global.asax inherit from NinjectHttpApplication:

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
```

Create a method to override kernel:

```
protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
{
   return new StandardKernel(new NinjectRepositoryModule(),
                             new NinjectAggregateServiceModule());
}
```

NijectRepositoryModule is where I bind my interfaces to concrete implementations:

```
public class NinjectRepositoryModule: NinjectModule
{
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IContactsRepository>().To<EFContactRepository>();
        }
}
```

Comment: I said on the first line that I am using Ninject,  and mentioned it again in my closing paragraph. IDependencyResolver in my example *is* Ninject.

Comment: I understand that and I was doing the same, but then I came across scenarios in MVC 3 where standard Ninject didn't do the job. E.g. injecting into attributes, so I have asked you whether you considered using MVC extension for ninject =) If that's not useful then I will happily remove the answer.

Comment: I installed Ninject using Nuget (https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application) the page says that does the same as extending NinjectHttpApplication. However, my testing shows that MVC 3 does not use Ninject to create Models for binding to Action ViewModels.

Comment: Ninject is working well injecting dependencies into other places. Controllers receive their dependencies fine for example.